# This doesn't get executed in sqlcmd and how to do it from python3.2

Tags: cmd, sqlcmd, python-3.3

I am trying to execute this in python from `call()` or `Popen()`:

```
sqlcmd -E -S .\ 
USE MASTER 
GO 
SELECT 
name AS [Logical_name], 
physical_name AS [File_Path], 
type_desc AS [File_Type], 
state_desc AS [State] 
FROM sys.master_files 
WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'AdventureWorksLT2008_old')
GO
```

it throws some error. Now, I wanted to see what the problem was. I made a .bat file of the commands. I executed it and only `sqlcmd -E -S .\` gets executed. Rest of the part doesn't. How can I get control of sqlcmd after cmd in python to execute rest of the code?
Can you please help.
Thanks

Comment: No matter the question, if you are getting an error related to your question, it would be helpful to post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an input option, such as `-q` and get rid of the `GO` command. Please [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) for examples. Try:

```
sqlcmd -E -S .\ -q "
SELECT 
name AS [Logical_name], 
physical_name AS [File_Path], 
type_desc AS [File_Type], 
state_desc AS [State] 
FROM sys.master_files 
WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'AdventureWorksLT2008_old')"
```

Or put it all in a single line if needed.